# Make std::cout output multiple string in the same row one after the other

Tags: c++

The title is a mess, it's probably a lot faster to just see the code

```
p1_dado = rand() % 6 + 1;

        switch (p1_dado) {
        case 1:
            cout << ".-----." << endl;
            cout << "|     |" << endl;
            cout << "|  o  |" << endl;
            cout << "|     |" << endl;
            cout << "._____." << endl << endl;
            p1_somma = p1_somma + p1_dado;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << ".-----." << endl;
            cout << "| o   |" << endl;
            cout << "|     |" << endl;
            cout << "|   o |" << endl;
            cout << "._____." << endl << endl;
            p1_ndadi--;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << ".-----." << endl;
            cout << "|o    |" << endl;
            cout << "|  o  |" << endl;
            cout << "|    o|" << endl;
            cout << "._____." << endl << endl;
            p1_somma = p1_somma + p1_dado;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << ".-----." << endl;
            cout << "| o o |" << endl;
            cout << "|     |" << endl;
            cout << "| o o |" << endl;
            cout << "._____." << endl << endl;
            p1_somma = p1_somma + p1_dado;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << ".-----." << endl;
            cout << "| o o |" << endl;
            cout << "|  o  |" << endl;
            cout << "| o o |" << endl;
            cout << "._____." << endl << endl;
            p1_ndadi--;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << ".-----." << endl;
            cout << "| o o |" << endl;
            cout << "| o o |" << endl;
            cout << "| o o |" << endl;
            cout << "._____." << endl << endl;
            p1_somma = p1_somma + p1_dado;
            break;
        }
```

I should also mention that this piece of code is in a for loop so the switch case will be ran for 4-5 times.
the way this outputs is all the dices on top of each other, is there a way to show all the dices in 1 "row" ? Like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

instead of:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: There's definitely a way, but it's not as easy as you want it to be.

Comment: Replace all of those `endl`s with `'\n'`s. You don't need to flush `cout` every time you write to it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you install something intercepting and rearranging the output the actual output can stay mostly unchanged. Since I'd be inclined to key sending compiled lines off a flush for the stream, the only change really necessary is replacing the [excessive use of `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) by uses of `'\n'`. That's something I **strongly** recommend anyway (for an explanation have a look at the [link](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/)).

So, assuming there is a something called `dicebuf` defined, the `main()` function could look like this (the interesting part is the first definition inside the function):

```
int main()
{
    dicebuf buf(std::cout);

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        int p1_dado = rand() % 6 + 1;
        switch (p1_dado) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << ".-----." << '\n';
            std::cout << "|     |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|  o  |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|     |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "._____." << '\n' << '\n';
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << ".-----." << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o   |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|     |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|   o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "._____." << '\n' << '\n';
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << ".-----." << '\n';
            std::cout << "|o    |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|  o  |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|    o|" << '\n';
            std::cout << "._____." << '\n' << '\n';
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << ".-----." << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|     |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "._____." << '\n' << '\n';
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << ".-----." << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "|  o  |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "._____." << '\n' << '\n';
            break;
        case 6:
            std::cout << ".-----." << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "| o o |" << '\n';
            std::cout << "._____." << '\n' << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the `dicebuf` constructor injects a custom stream buffer which aggregates lines. It simply doesn't output things but just adds characters to a current row. If a newline (`'\n'`) is encountered, it goes to the next row. If a two newlines in a row are encountered, it assumes it time to go back to the top and carry on adding to the current line.

Creating such a utility intercepting the output is done by implementing a suitable stream buffer, i.e., a class derived from `std::streambuf`. Here is an example implementation:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct dicebuf
    : std::streambuf
{
    std::ostream&                       out;
    std::streambuf*                     sbuf;
    std::vector<std::string>            rows;
    std::vector<std::string>::size_type row;
public:
    dicebuf(std::ostream& out)
        : out(out)
        , sbuf(out.rdbuf())
        , rows(1)
        , row(0) {
        out.rdbuf(this);
    }
    ~dicebuf() {
        this->sync();
        this->out.rdbuf(this->sbuf);
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            if (c == '\n') {
                if (this->rows[this->row].empty()) {
                    this->row = 0;
                }
                else {
                    ++this->row;
                    if (this->rows.size() == this->row) {
                        this->rows.push_back(std::string());
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                this->rows[this->row].push_back(c);
            }

        }
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
        std::ostream out(this->sbuf);
        std::copy(this->rows.begin(), this->rows.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, "\n"));
        this->sbuf->pubsync();
        this->row = 0;
        this->rows.resize(0);
        this->rows.push_back(std::string());
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Together with the `main()` above it should produce the output as desired. If you want multiple lines with results, you'll just inject a flush, e.g., using

```
std::flush;
```

at strategic points.

Comment: I'm very new to programming so i can't understand much of what you said and much of the code. I know the output won't change, but just the way it shows and that's what i want. What about the solution of the user @rbaghbanli ? I can't get it to work...

Comment: @GiorgioTocco: I'm confused: it seems you are saying that my solution exactly does what you want it to do. Still, you are asking how to make the inferior solution work...?

Comment: @GiorgioTocco: the main problem with the other answer is that it interferes with the logic substantially. You end up essentially turning some of the logic inside out. I strongly prefer to have some code deal with these things than contorting the logic, even if it comes at some costs (using the stream buffer _is_ a bit slower but I doubt it is possible to measure the difference in typical uses).

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
char* hline = ".-----.";
char* dice[6][3] = { {"|     |", "|  o  |", "|     |" }, { ... }}; // 3 middle lines for each dice

for (int l=0; l < 5; ++l) {
  for(int i=0; i < 6; ++i) // or any random dice sequence with index = dice value - 1
    cout << (l == 0 || l == 4) ? hline : dice[i][l-1] << " ";
  cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The ide is telling me an error on
 'dice[i][i-1]'
i declared i as = 0 and put all 3 middle lines for each dice

Comment: for (int l=0; i < 5; ++l) is wrong, replace i < 5 with l < 5.

Comment: still gives me om dice[i][i-1]:
expression must have integral or enum type

Comment: Here is a quick run-down of coding issues I spotted: 1. string literals can't be assigned to `char*`, i.e., `hline` and `dice` should use `char const*`; 2. in the first `for` loop the `i` should be `l` (really easy to spot...); 3. the conditional operator has lower precedence than the shift operator, i.e., the expression needs parenthesis.

Comment: dice[i][l-1], not i-1. Fixed.